# What does CallingThreadDispatcher do?

Tags: scala, testing, akka

I came across this code and wonder what CallingThreadDispatcher does.
I can comment out

```
val dispatcherId = CallingThreadDispatcher.Id
val props = Props[Greeter].withDispatcher(dispatcherId)
```

and this test will still work

```
class GreeterTest extends TestKit(testSystem)
  with WordSpecLike
  with MustMatchers
  with StopSystemAfterAll {

  "The Greeter" must {
    "say Hello World! when a Greeting(\"World\") is sent to it" in {
      val dispatcherId = CallingThreadDispatcher.Id
      val props = Props[Greeter].withDispatcher(dispatcherId)
      val greeter = system.actorOf(props)
      EventFilter.info(message = "Hello World!", occurrences = 1).intercept {
        greeter ! Greeting("World")
      }
    }
  }
}

object GreeterTest {
  val testSystem = {
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString("""akka.loggers = [akka.testkit.TestEventListener]""")
    ActorSystem("testSystem", config)
  }
}
```

So what does CallingThreadDispatcher do? and why do we need it?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`CallingThreadDispatcher`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/testkit/CallingThreadDispatcher.scala#L106) is pretty good:

```
* Dispatcher which runs invocations on the current thread only. This
* dispatcher does not create any new threads, but it can be used from
* different threads concurrently for the same actor. The dispatch strategy is
* to run on the current thread unless the target actor is either suspendSwitch or
* already running on the current thread (if it is running on a different
* thread, then this thread will block until that other invocation is
* finished); if the invocation is not run, it is queued in a thread-local
* queue to be executed once the active invocation further up the call stack
* finishes. This leads to completely deterministic execution order if only one
* thread is used.
```

It is used in unit tests because it is convenient for actors to have *deterministic* order of execution when you're testing a particular unit of the code. As you see, this isn't mandatory for the test you're running and also works without it.